# What do you call a person who can "read a room" and adapt socially by doing so?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms, idiom-requests

What word or words could I use to describe being able to read a room and adapt to that social setting by doing so? I have an interview and I'm trying to list strengths. I work in medical offices directly with the doctors assisting them, and their demeanor and attitudes can switch quickly so it's important to be able to recognize that quickly.

Comment: You might want to move this to workplace.SE, since resume advice is only partially aligned with English. I would spell things out as you have here using fewer words. Resumes should be easy to scan, and really aren't read.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call them a **social chameleon**.
I believe I had heard it before, but apparently (based on internet search results) it's quite an established idiom.
[A New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/1985/03/12/science/social-chameleon-may-pay-emotional-price.html) delves into the phenomenon, and lists a few key characteristics:

> - They pay careful attention to social cues, scrutinizing others with keenness so as to know what is expected of them before making a response.
> - In order to get along and to be liked, they try to be as others expect them to be. For example, they try to make people they dislike think they are friendly with them.
> - They use their social abilities to mold their appearance as disparate situations demand, so that, as some put it, ''With different people I act like a very different person.''

They liken this personality trait to Woody Allen's Zelig (whom I'm not familiar with, but who might be a clear illustration).

Answer (score 0):

I would call them a social, flexible or all-round person. These adjectives mean skilled, versatile, adaptable.

Being more specific:

> Social: Enjoying spending time with other people; connected with your position in society (Oxford, https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/social_1).
>
> Flexible: Able to change or be changed easily according to the situation (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/flexible).
>
> All-round: Considered in or encompassing all aspects; COMPREHENSIVE; 2.
> Competent in many fields.([https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all-round#:~:text=1,%3A%20competent%20in%20many%20fields](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all-round#:%7E:text=1,%3A%20competent%20in%20many%20fields)).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Such a person is [perceptive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/perceptive).

> **perceptive**
> *adjective*
>
> able to notice and understand things that many other people do not notice

From Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: That is the word that came to my mind also. But I think to answer the question you need a phrase that gives it a social context: "perceptive of the social relationships of members of a group" or something more pithy.

Comment: @David but isn't CV writing off-topic? Perhaps "perceptive and responsive in an interactive situation."

Comment: Yes. But, then I assumed you had extracted the question from that context.

Comment: @David the OP says "I have an interview and I'm trying to list strengths."

Comment: But you answered rather than edited his question or voted to close. I find it difficult to understand why list members in general (not you personally) do not do the recommended thing and improve questions. On an English Language site it surprises me that ungrammatical or badly formulated titles are answered but are left untouched. But that's something for meta.